# Solid Mensuration Problem

Tags: geometry

i'm stuck with this problem, trying to solve it but i always get the wrong answer.

A mound of earth in the form of a solid has a rectangular base 17m long and 8.62m wide. Its perpendicular height is 5m and the length on the top is 8.56m. Find the volume of cubic meters of earth in the mound.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At left and right you have two pyramids, with height $5\ $m and easy to compute base area. At center you have a triangular prism, with height $8.56\ $m and easy to compute base area. I think you should be able to do it right now.